# Promise.all in not waiting to finish the inner Promise.all completion

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

```
let obj = [
  {
    Id: 1,
    name: 'david',
    Address:[{
      city: 'dubai',
      country: 'UAE'
    }]
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    name: 'Ram',
    Address: [{
      city: 'US',
      country: 'India'
    },
    {
      city: 'Delhi1',
      country: 'India1'
    }]
  }
];

async function fun() {
await Promise.all(obj.map(async info => {
      console.log('info', JSON.stringify(info));
      await Promise.all(info.Address.map(async (items, index) => {
        console.log('ParentItems IsParentLossCapability',);
        let pr = await firstFunction();
        console.log('promise resolved: ' + pr)
        console.log('next step');
      }));
      console.log('UpdatedInfo', JSON.stringify(obj));
    }));
}
 async function firstFunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let y = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        y++;
      }
      console.log('loop completed');
      resolve(y);
    }, 2000);
  });
 }

fun();
```

What I am getting output like below, it says

1. info
2. info
3. loop completed
4. promise resolved
5. next step
6. UpdatedInfo
7. Loop completed
8. next step
9. UpdatedInfo

It should give output like this,

1. info
2. loop completed
3. Promise resolved: 10
4. next step
5. UpdatedInfo
6. info
7. loop completed
8. promise resolved: 10
9. next step
10. UpdatedInfo

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.map(async (e) => {...})`, all the functions start executing at the same time. `await Promise.all(arr.map(async (e) => {...}))` waits for *all of them* to finish, but it's still parallel.

What you want is to make them sequential. Either you can use a for loop:

```
for (let info of obj) {
      console.log('info', JSON.stringify(info));
      for (let index = 0 ; index < info.Address.length; index++) {
      let items = info.Address[index];
        console.log('ParentItems IsParentLossCapability',);
        let pr = await firstFunction();
        console.log('promise resolved: ' + pr)
        console.log('next step');
      }
      console.log('UpdatedInfo', JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

or use an async reduce:

```
await obj.reduce(async (memo, info) => {
      await memo;
      console.log('info', JSON.stringify(info));
      await info.Address.reduce(async (memo2, items, index) => {
        await memo2;
        console.log('ParentItems IsParentLossCapability',);
        let pr = await firstFunction();
        console.log('promise resolved: ' + pr)
        console.log('next step');
      }), Promise.resolve());
      console.log('UpdatedInfo', JSON.stringify(obj));
    }, Promise.resolve());
```